# How to find distance (by road) between 2 geo points in Android application?

Tags: android, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I am developing an Android application. I need to find the distance between two geo coordinates.

I used `Location.distanceBetween()` and `Location.distanceTo()` functions. These functions give the straight distance, but the actual distance is different when we travel by road.

I want the distance between two geo points when the user travels by road. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I think you will have to use the distance matrix service. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix?hl=it-IT

Comment: alkis, that's the JavaScript API... A browser will be needed, or a JS engine.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) to get a "route" from GeoPoint X to GeoPoint Y. You'll get a list of points, that represent lines (legs, or segments) that you'll need to take to reach Y from X.

You can measure the distances between the points but DO *NOT* DO THAT because the XML or JSON result *will* contain the total distance of the route. You can use the information about each line to draw a polyline on the map.

There doesn't seem to be an Android API, only an API that returns XML or JSON that you'll need to parse. Like what is done here: [Google Maps Directions - Which API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338163/google-maps-directions-which-api)