# Get distance from GPS position and some marker B using Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

i'm developing an App in Android that check some parameters like Fuel Level from OBD port and with this parameter i would like to advice the user that the Fuel level is inadeguate for the entire travel.

So i need to get distance in Km from GPS or phone position to some Marker B in the map (like fuel shop).
It's possible to get distance from phone position and some specified Marker B without integrate a Google Maps inside my application?
And only if the user press "Ok guide me to point B" i use the app google maps for the navigation?

I see in the documentations that i can select some type of search with a `Place Picker` and now i need the distance from selected position and my position and check if the fuel is enough for the entire travel.

Some suggestions?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14394403/6950238) is the solution without using Google Maps, but this is distance between points, not via road.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find distance (by road) between 2 geo points in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249693/how-to-find-distance-by-road-between-2-geo-points-in-android-application)

Answer (score 1):

```
var current_coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude1, longitude1);
var shop_coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude2, longitude2);

var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(current_coords, shop_coords)
```

**NOTE**: THIS WILL CALCULATE DIRECT DISTANCE BETWEEN TWO POINTS.MEANS NOT 
DISTANCE VIA ROAD

Comment: Thanks, but i need the Road distance for check if the fuel is enough!
There is some way?

current_coords i think that i take from my marker via GPS...but how i get the shop_coords that you write?

Comment: @Dario Then you should go for DistanceMatric API.